# How to delete duplicate based on a portion of list item only in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following data set (showing just the snapshot)

```
data = {{0.1, 0.2, 5}, {0.1, 0.3, 7}, {0.2, 0.2, 1}, {0.1, 0.2, 9}}
```

In other words, the data is in the format of {A, B, C}.
I want to delete duplicate based on A & B only.
I would like the output to be (effectively removing the last item as in the example)

```
{{0.1, 0.2, 5}, {0.1, 0.3, 7}, {0.2, 0.2, 1}}
```

DeleteDuplicates[data] doesn't work for me as it uses all A, B and C in the duplicate detection and removal.

Comment: Read the documentation of `DeleteDuplicates`.  The function takes an optional 2nd argument which is used to test whether 2 elements are duplicates.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark what is the policy about rtfm questions on SO?

Comment: The accepted answer provided by @ogerard is much more helpful to novice users than the documentation. Refer to the accepted answer for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more or less explained in the documentation for `DeleteDuplicates`.

```
DeleteDuplicates[data, Take[#1, 2] == Take[#2, 2] &]
```

should do what you want : it defines an equality function of any two first-level elements of *data* (#1 and #2) as equality of the first two sub-elements (that's what Take[ ..., 2] does) .